# c# / LINQ - Average the number of enquiries per day, week and month over a time period

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ Query:

```
model.TotalEnquiries = enquiriesDbContext.Enquiries.Where(x => x.CustomerAccountNumber == formModel.CustomerAccNo)
                   .Where(x => x.EnquiryDate >= startDate).Where(x => x.EnquiryDate <= endDate).Count();
```

This works fine as it'll return a value of say, 60, between 2 specified time periods, but what I'd like to do is find the average number of enquiries per day, week and month for this period, is it possible in LINQ?

Comment: Divide it by the number of days...

Comment: Before you count them you have to find the real range of days (Minimum() and Maximum()) then you can divide the count by the number of days.

Comment: @Adriano: Why would you want to find the real range of days? If there's only one enquiry in a year, that doesn't make it an average of 1 per day for that year, just because the minimum and maximum dates would be the same.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right...it's time to shutdown the computer to go the beach...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well given that you've specified the period yourself, it's easy:

```
var averagePerDay = total / (endDate - startDate).TotalDays;
```

EDIT: I see you're changing the goalposts... if you want to get averages for different date ranges *in one query* then it's going to be tricky. Personally, unless there's a huge amount of data, I'd probably fetch all the enquiry dates within the appropriate range, and then process it locally, which is likely to be easier than trying to minimize the number of SQL queries while still keeping them smart.

Averaging by month over an arbitrary period is conceptually tricky: how many months are in the period of (say) February 16th to April 7th? Three different month lengths are involved.

Of course, you may mean "average by day, grouping by month" (e.g. average by day in January, average by day in February" etc) which is entirely different. This is why you need to be precise about requirements.

Comment: The question has been updated to include average per week and month.  Given that `TimeSpan` does not have a `TotalWeeks`/`TotalMonths`, is there an easy way to do this?  The simple way would be to divide the `TotalDays` by 7 or 30.  However, this does not deal with the variance in the the length of the months.  In SQL we could just do a `datediff` to get this.  I haven't found a good way to do this in .NET.

Comment: And now the OP has removed that from the question.  This is still something I am interested in getting your opinion on.

Comment: @cadrell0: They've put it back again. I'll edit my answer very slightly, but frankly I don't have a lot of interest in trying to hit moving targets :(

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited wrong question, I put it back! Im still interested in finding how to get the average per day, week and month

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: As I've added in my edit, "per month" is tricky unless you're using whole months. Per week would presumably be per day divided by 7...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a GROUP BY to group the entries by day, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) (with samples)

Otherwise you'll need to settle for doing an average via SUM/COUNT which gives you less insight into the distribution, trends, etc.

Comment: Why would you need to group by anything, when we have the total count and the number of days already?